# Not able to get the correct column names of CLOB type columns despite using DBMS_LOB.substr(myColumn, 3000)

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle11g

I am using `Oracle Database 11g Enterprise Edition Release 11.2.0.3.0 - 64bit Production` . I have two columns declared as `CLOB` in a table and I want to read the data from the table using `SYS_REFCURSOR`. But I am getting the correct data and column names from all the columns except the columns that declared as `CLOB`. The following is my stored procedure:

```
create or replace
procedure ZSPPQCSGAPHISTORY
(
    P_MEMBERID in types.char20,
    P_CAREGAPCODE   in types.char90, cur in out SYS_REFCURSOR
)

authid current_user
as
begin
open cur for select
            A.MEMBERID,
      A.CAREGAPCODE,
      A.RATINGPERIOD,
            A.DISCUSSEDDATETIME, 
            A.DISCUSSEDUSERID, 
            A.COMPLETEDDATE, 
            DBMS_LOB.substr(A.CALLSCRIPT, 3000),
            DBMS_LOB.substr(A.NOTES, 3000)
            from PQCSCGAP A 
            where A.MEMBERID=P_MEMBERID
            and A.CAREGAPCODE=P_CAREGAPCODE order by DISCUSSEDDATETIME desc;

end;
```

I am using `DBMS_LOB.substr(myColumn, 3000)` to read the data, but still I am not getting the correct column names from the columns declared as `CLOB` type. Any ideas on how to tackle this issue?

Comment: Can you execute only the select statement and see if it returns data or not.

Comment: Actually it is able to fetch data, but with different column names such as DBMS_LOB.substr(A.NOTES, 3000).I want the original column names. I am sorry if I confused you.

Comment: You should give alias in the select statement  like:   DBMS_LOB.substr(A.CALLSCRIPT, 3000) as CALLSCRIPT,

Comment: That's perfect..!! +1 for the solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> You should give alias in the select statement like: DBMS_LOB.substr(A.CALLSCRIPT, 3000) as CALLSCRIPT, – Mottor

It's my mistake that I haven't used `Alias` names for the column of `CLOB` type.So, The following modified stored procedure works:

```
create or replace
procedure ZSPPQCSGAPHISTORY
(
    P_MEMBERID in types.char20,
    P_CAREGAPCODE   in types.char90, cur in out SYS_REFCURSOR
)

authid current_user
as
begin
open cur for select
            A.MEMBERID,
      A.CAREGAPCODE,
      A.RATINGPERIOD,
            A.DISCUSSEDDATETIME, 
            A.DISCUSSEDUSERID, 
            A.COMPLETEDDATE, 
          DBMS_LOB.substr(A.CALLSCRIPT, 3000) AS CALLSCRIPT,
      DBMS_LOB.substr(A.NOTES, 3000) AS NOTES
            from PQCSCGAP A 
            where A.MEMBERID=P_MEMBERID
            and A.CAREGAPCODE=P_CAREGAPCODE order by DISCUSSEDDATETIME desc;

end;
```